# I have this 64 gig microSD and it seems I can't utilize it

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage, lg-g4

I have an LG Stylo with 16GB internal storage and just bought a 64GB microSD because I was tired of running out of space. So I manually moved all of the apps I could to the external storage. This freed up a few gigs. Now I'm goinf to update an app and my internal is up to 15.4 gigs?? Why? My apps are still listed under the "Internal Storage" section but once I select an app, it states it is in External Storage. So why is this happening? Is it leaving an undisclosed amount of data inside anyway? Is this a bug? I'm debating on deleting one of the apps through internal storage and see if it wipes it off my SD. By the way, my 64 gig is hardly being used. Maybe 6 gigs tops

Answer (score 1):

You can't move apps to memory card. It is possible only if sd card is adopted or via apps like link2sd (require root). Yes there is option move to sd card in app manager but that moves small amount of data to sd. So if you want more space for apps adopt your SD card and that's it. Some bare minimum is class 10 SD card or UHS I if you phone support it.

Comment: Is there a workaround without rooting my phone?

Comment: @Tyler Seres https://www.xda-developers.com/enable-adoptable-storage-for-galaxy-s7-and-s7-edge/ this works on any 6+ android